# Concatenate string and for each in php

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<?php echo 'Name: ' foreach ( $names as $k => $v ) {
                if (in_array($k, $d)) {
                 echo $v;
               }
             }  
?>
```

I think i'm getting the quotes incorrect.. Any ideas?

Comment: `echo 'Name: '` -> `echo 'Name: ';` ... and done

Comment: What it is in `$names`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php echo 'Name: ';
      foreach ( $names as $k => $v ) {
                if (in_array($k, $d)) {
                 echo $v;
               }
             }  
?>
```

you forgot to add `;` in your code!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo 'Name: '; 
foreach ( $names as $k => $v ) {
    if (in_array($k, $d)) {
        echo $v;
    }
}  
?>
```